# Summing columns in a text file

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
 TOPIC:topic_0 2056
 ab  2.0
 cd  5.0
 ef  3.0
 gh  10.0

 TOPIC:topic_1 1000
 aa  3.0
 bd  5.0
 gh  2.0
```

and so on......till TOPIC:topic_2000. The first line is the topic and it's weight. That is, I have the words in that specific topic and their respective weights.

Now, I want to sum up the second column of each topic and check what value it gives. That is, I want to get the output as:

```
 Topic:topic_0  20
 Topic:topic_1  10
```

That is, the topic number and the sum of column value (that is in topic 1, the weights of the words are 2,5,3,10). I tried using:

```
with open('Input.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        columns = line.split(' ')
        value = columns[0]

        if value[:6] == 'TOPIC:':
            total_value = columns[1]
            total_value = total_value[:-1]
            total_values = float(total_value)
            #print '\n'
            print columns[0]
```

But, I am not sure how to proceed from this. This is just printing the topic numbers. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

input = """
TOPIC:topic_0 2056
 ab  2.0
 cd  5.0
 ef  3.0
 gh  10.0

 TOPIC:topic_1 1000
 aa  3.0
 bd  5.0
 gh  2.0
"""

result = {}
for line in input.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue

    columns = re.split(r"\s+", line)
    value = columns[0]
    if value[:6] == 'TOPIC:':
        result[value] = []
        points = result[value]
        continue

    points.append(float(columns[1]))

for k, v in result.items():
    print k, sum(v)
```

Comment: my input file has 2000 such topics. can I load the input file and perform the same code on it ?

Comment: simply replace `input.splitlines()` to your original code. it depends on your data size, 2000 isn't a big number to me consider the gigabyte of memory nowadays.

Comment: It is giving me an error "list object has no attribute split", when I used 
     with open('assigned0_lda01_100.txt','r') as f:
     f1 = f.read().split()        
     result = {}
    for line in f1.split():
      line1 = line.strip()

Comment: read() returns the whole file content... your original code is good.  `with open('Input.txt') as f:
    for line in f: ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Works with both Python 2.7 and 3.5

```
import re;

total = 0
temp = ''
topic = {}
p = re.compile('[a-z]*')

with open('Input.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue

        if line.startswith('TOPIC:'):
            temp = (line.split(' ')[0]).replace('TOPIC:', '')
            topic[temp] = 0;
        else:
            value = p.sub('', line).strip()
            topic[temp] = float(topic[temp]) + float(value)

for key in topic:
    print ("Topic:%s %s" % (key, topic[key]))
```

Result:

```
$ /c/Python27/python.exe input.py
Topic:topic_1 10.0
Topic:topic_0 20.0
```